# Total Variation Measure Defined by Measurable Function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Letting $\mu$ be a positive measure, $f\in L^1(d\mu)$ measurable, and a second measure $\omega$ given by 
$$ \omega(W)\;=\;\int_W f\:d\mu$$
Can it be shown that 
$$|\omega|(W)\;=\;\int_W |f| \, d\mu\text{ ?}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P = \{ x \in \Omega : f(x) \ge 0 \}$ and $N = \{ x \in \Omega : f(x) < 0 \}$. Then it one can show directly by the definition that $W = P \cup N$ is a [Hahn decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem) of the space $\Omega$ with respect to the measure $\omega$. It is then easy to see that $\omega_+$ and $\omega_-$ defined by

$$
\omega_+(W) = \int_{P \cap W} f \, d\mu = \int_{P \cap W} |f| \, d\mu, \quad \omega_-(W) = \int_{N \cap W} -f \, d\mu = \int_{N \cap W} |f| \, d\mu.
$$

is a [Jordan decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem) of $\omega$. By the uniqueness of the Jordan decomposition and the definition of the total variation measure, we have $|\omega| = \omega_+ + \omega_-$ so

$$
|\omega|(W) = \int_W |f| d\, \mu.
$$